# Boss GT-100 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: alsa

I wish to use BOSS GT-100 for recording some sound in Ubuntu 12.04. When I connect this device via usb and power it on, I see it in `lsusb`, but it seems that it is not recognized to be an audio device. I followed these instructions: [Boss GT-100 on Linux](http://www.delta-xi.net/#038), but it is still not recognized. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Support for the Boss GT-100 [has been added to the ALSA kernel source](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.commits.head/326131) two weeks ago (although it contains the very same code as on the page you mentioned), so you may either compile the sources from git or keep on waiting til your distribution adds the new code. It works like a charm for me in Ubuntu 12.04 and Mint Maya.

Erik (from delta-xi.net)